# What are the issues with not enter TYPE in your SCRIPT tags

Tags: javascript

The green wiggly line in Visual Studio haunts me and I can't let it persist there but what is the real danger in just typing `<SCRIPT>`  as opposed to `<SCRIPT Type='text/javascript'>` ?

It seems like every tutorial or article I read demonstrates with only `'<SCRIPT>'` ... so is there any issue with not adding a type?

Comment: No issues, as `text/javascript` is the default. But for clarity, everybody types it out…

Comment: As long as you're using the HTML5 DOCTYPE (`<!DOCTYPE html>`), ommitting the `type` attribute defaults to "text/javascript"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799601/various-script-type-attributes-and-vanilla-js-what-makes-difference-in-user-age

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before HTML5 you were supposed to specify `type="text/javascript"` (or some other type) for all your `<script>` tags - now in HTML5 it's the default, but either you are not using HTML5 or Visual Studio does not know about this fact.

However, `<script>` has *always* been considered JavaScript by browsers so even before the `type` was officially optional it was technically optional. That's why you often see it.

Comment: And all browsers did consider the type to be JavaScript by default, so there's not even a problem with old browsers.

Answer (score 1):

There would be an issue you are holding content inside the script tag that is not `text/javascript`. Example would be where you're holding a `template`, the browser would try to execute it as a script.

Answer (score 1):

Until html 4 at least it was required -

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html

```
<!ELEMENT SCRIPT - - %Script;          -- script statements -->
<!ATTLIST SCRIPT
  charset     %Charset;      #IMPLIED  -- char encoding of linked resource --
  type        %ContentType;  #REQUIRED -- content type of script language --
  src         %URI;          #IMPLIED  -- URI for an external script --
  defer       (defer)        #IMPLIED  -- UA may defer execution of script --
  >
```